# Symfony templates in /app or bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, bundle

Symfony best practices say to store twig templates in `/app/ressources/views`. But its also advised to use several bundles for specific functions. So, wouldnt it be better to store the template also inside the bundles? Maybe the best practices is only suitable for projects that use only AppBundle and external bundles?

Answer (score 1):

here's how I do

For general template

**app/Resources/views/base.html.twig**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Application{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
```

For un bundle

**src/App/ActuBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig**

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

A module in bundle

**src/App/ActuBundle/Resources/views/News/index.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'AppActuBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

This good practice regarding the views of your application, not the bundle.

So for your bundles create templates in your bundle

Comment: but everything should be a bundle in symfony, so I should store the appBundle templates in app/ but the templates of other bundles in src/xxBundle, even if its not an external bundle?